# Kafka MirrorMaker 2 logging WARN message of TopicExistsException

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I'm running MirrorMaker 2 for replicating the data between 2 Kafka clusters. After starting the service, and waiting for a while, the **connect.logs** contain multiple warning messages for each individual topics as follows:

```
[2023-06-19 03:00:16,712] WARN [MirrorSourceConnector|worker] Could not create topic trigger_process. (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector:381)
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'test_topic' already exists.
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:632)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaCompletableFuture.kafkaCompleteExceptionally(KafkaCompletableFuture.java:49)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.completeExceptionally(KafkaFutureImpl.java:130)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$1.handleResponse(KafkaAdminClient.java:1629)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.handleResponses(KafkaAdminClient.java:1268)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1421)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1344)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'test_topic' already exists.
```

Is this an expected log statement? Is there something I can do to avoid them?

I was not expecting the log files to flood with the exception above, and I am not sure if it's expected.

Comment: did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: I am seeing the same issues using on AWS MSK using MSK Connect version 2.7.1. It appears to be related to this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8370

Answer (score 0):

for those who have this problem.. before running mirrormaker, you must set the following ACL (i used the command-config param bcoz i'm using sasl/scram):

```
    ./kafka-acls.sh \
  --bootstrap-server ${brokers} \
  --add \
  --allow-principal User:master \
  --operation All \
  --topic=* group=* \
  --command-config $USER_HOME/toolbox/kafka_2.12-3.3.1/config/connector.properties
```

Comment: I am seeing this exception for a cluster that has "allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found" = true